# php regular expression for video swf

Tags: php, regex, video, flash

iwant to get the video url from a object/embed html source. i read i can use regular expression to get it but me and regular expression are no friends

so heres what i have:

```
<?php 

function src($text) {
    $text = str_replace('"', '', $text);
    $text = str_replace('src=', '', $text);
    $temporary = explode('<embed', $text);
    $temporary = $temporary[1];
    $temporary = explode(' ', trim($temporary));
    return $temporary[0];
} 

$html = '
<object width="180" height="220">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.domain.com/video/video1.swf"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.domain.com/video/video1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="180" height="220"></embed>
</object>
'; 

echo src($html);
```

this works but is it better in regular expression?

i am using lamp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A regular expression is better for this case because the `src` might never be at the first attribute, therefore this won't work.

Here's what I recommend:

```
function src($html) {
 if(preg_match('#<embed[^>]*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'](.*?)></embed>#si', stripslashes($html), $src)) {
  return $src[1];
 }
 return ''; // or any other error if you need
}

echo src($html);
```

will output: `http://www.domain.com/video/video1.swf`

`[^>]` matches a single character that is not contained within the brackets. [^>] matches any character other than `>`

`["\']` matches `src="` or `src='`

`(.*?)` Dot (.) means match any character.  Star (*) means zero or more times.  And question mark (?) means be greedy and keep going as long as the pattern still matches.  Put it all together, it means try and match any character, zero or more times, and get as many as you can

`/i` is case insensitive

Here's more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Regarding the `["|\']` subexpression... The `|` char is _NOT_ a metacharacter within a character class (you cannot do alternation within a char class). What you want here is simply `["']`.

Comment: The `?` means NOT greedy, not be greedy.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a DOM parser; it's designed to do this kind of work.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$embed = $dom->getElementsByTagName('embed');

if ($embed->length) {
   $embed = $embed->item(0);

   if ($embed->hasAttribute('src')) {
       $src = $embed->getAttribute('src');
       // `$src` holds the `src` attribute of the `embed` element.  
   }
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8UU0ws).

Comment: i get: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [function.DOMDocument-loadHTML]: Unexpected end tag : param in Entity, line: 17 in test.php on line24

Comment: @E.G.: That's a warning because your HTML is invalid. It still works.

Comment: @EscoMaji ...and is your HTML invalid too?

Comment: @Derek What would you suggest then? And how is saying that `DOMDocument` is slow relevant to an application you know nothing about?

Comment: @alex i copied the code from the question, i rather use this solution since its WAY more simple, but am i doing something wrong? - i get the error at this line: ` $dom->loadHTML($html); `

Comment: @EscoMaji It's only a parse warning, you don't have to worry too much about it.