# check if string contain  ( CR, LF or CF or LF) or not  using PHP

Tags: php, string

I have  a string and I want to control the content of the string it
contain `( CR, LF or CRLF)`or not?

```
 if (no CR, LF or CF or LF) in string: 
    echo 'no sepator';
  else:
     echo 'have some separator';
```

Anyone here could tell me the ways to do this in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this function checks that input string has any combination of new line characters, or not.

```
function hasNewLine($str) {
    $found = false;
    foreach (array("\r", "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r") as $token) {
        if (strpos($str, $token) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

and there's another version of this function which detects the given string **ends** with new line characters:

```
function endsWithNewLine($str) {
    $found = false;
    foreach (array("\r", "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r") as $token) {
        $desiredPos = strlen($str) - strlen($token);
        if (strpos($str, $token) === $desiredPos) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Comment: i recommend to optimize your code and the `endsWithNewLine`, you can use: `if(trim($str) !== $str)` { .. } way easier

Comment: well, it's nice code from someone who still learns the basics, but upvote it?

Comment: Sorry to disagree here but `for loop` + `str_pos` and if the character is found at the beginning of a string and that string is 500k long you still go through ALL of it? Beginning PHP? well now it's learning time! - The code works, i agree, but personally there's a better way to do it

Comment: I'm not a beginner in php! i have about two years experience! i know, there maybe dozen of ways to improve the function. i just wanted to answer quickly...:(

Comment: @Derek i think strpos function is intelligent enough to just find the first match in the string.

Comment: @try2fly.b4ucry well now you know a better and faster way, keep phping!

Comment: look, there's tons of way to do things, i just wanted you to be aware of answering fast on stackoverflow might not get you the best answer all the time

Comment: @Derek 
Note:  
If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: @try2fly.b4ucry where's the benchmark of this? and when i meant faster, i meant my code is 1 line of code whereas, i don't create an array each time i do a foreach loop then compare

Comment: @try2fly.b4ucry i completely agree with you but knowing PHP does not mean HOW to program in PHP - I was expecting more form you with 2 years of exp than this code I'm sorry

Answer (score 5):

```
function hasNewLine($str) {
    return (strpos($str, "\n") !== false) || (strpos($str, "\r") !== false);
}
var_dump(hasNewLine("my stringn\n\rmy string"));
```

if you are looking for `\n` in a `\n\r` you don't need to look for `\n\r` since the `\n` is already in the `\n\r` string.

Comment: `strstr` is sloooooooow! Why not `strpos()`? ;)

Comment: @Derek PHP has no `str_pos()` function.

Comment: i guess that's what happen when you try to reply fast!

Comment: @alex strstr is not slow. please, quit such a superstition and trolling

Comment: Derek, look, you have made your code worse just because some troll wanted to tease you.

Comment: @Col I wrote that comment in reaction to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291030/php-regular-expression-for-video-swf/8291050#comment10371006_8291050).

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel  Also, PHP documentation for `strstr()` states *If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function `strpos()` instead.* [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).